# number of distinct de Bruijn sequences B(n,k)

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I am trying to find out where does the formula for finding the number of all distinct de Bruijn sequences come from.
Wikipedia page
:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_sequence
here is the formula part:[B(n,k)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8TGzW.png)

p.s: This is not homework! I'm just self-studying Graph Theory.

Comment: See Van Lint and Wilson, "A Course in Combinatorics" for the $k=2$ case (the general case is similar I'm sure). Basically, you proceed by induction using the de Bruijn graphs.

Comment: @Casteels thanks for your help :)

Comment: See "Circuits and trees in oriented linear graphs" by de Bruijn and van Aardenne-Ehrenfest for a proof of the general case.