# Binary sequences of length $N$ including all numbers upto $N$

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms, modular-arithmetic, binary

Consider numbers $n$ and $N = 2^n$ and define a binary sequence $b = [b_0,\dots,b_{N-1}]$, $b_i \in \{0,1\}$, to be **complete** or **to include all numbers upto $N$** when for each number $0 \leq i < N$ there is a number $0 \leq j < N$ such that

$$i = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} b_{(j+k)\,\text{mod}\, N}\cdot 2^k$$

The easiest thing to do is to go through all binary sequences of length $N$ and check if they are complete.

Examples:

```
n = 2: [1,1,0,0] => [3,1,0,2]
n = 3: [1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0] => [5,6,7,3,1,0,4,2]
n = 4: [1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0] => [15,7,11,5,10,13,6,3,9,4,2,1,0,8,12,14]
       [1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0] => [11,5,10,13,14,15,7,3,9,4,2,1,0,8,12,6]
```

For $n=2$ there are $2^{2^2} = 16$ sequences, $4= 2^2$ being complete.

For $n=3$ there are $2^{2^3} = 256$ sequences, $16 = 2^4$ being complete.

For $n = 4$ there are $2^{2^4} = 65,536$ sequences, $256 = 2^8$ being complete.

**Question 1**: Is it true that the number of complete sequences for given $n$ is $2^{2^{n-1}}$ or – equivalently – the square root of the number of all sequences? How to prove it?

**Question 2**: Which properties must complete sequences have, except for (i) containing the same number of 0s and 1s, (ii) containing exactly two runs of length $n$, and (iii) not containing runs longer than $n$?

**Question 3**: Which properties must the coded number sequences have? Must they be "random" in a way?

**Question 4**: Since already for $n=5$ with $2^{2^5} = 4,294,967,296$ binary sequences a brut force search for complete sequences is not opportune: How do I compute a complete sequence for any given $n$? What's the runtime $\mathcal{O}(f(n))$ of the algorithm?

Comment: The keyword you want is "De Bruijn sequence"

Comment: These are [binary de Bruijn sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_sequence). The wiki article gives the formula $2^{2^n-n-1}$ for the number, and [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2138183/number-of-distinct-de-bruijn-sequences-bn-k?r=SearchResults&s=5%7C161.2078) points to proofs of that formula in the literature, answering question 1. For question 4, you just need to find an Eulerian cycle in the de Bruijn graph, for which Hierholzer's algorithm is quite efficient. I think questions 2 and 3 are to vague.

Comment: @MikeEarnest: Thanks for the comment. I admit that questions 2 and 3 are vague, but nevertheless you may have an idea what I'm asking for. If so, is any "property" obvious for you, like (i) to (iii) in question 2?

Comment: Mistake in my last comment; the number of sequence is actually $2^{2^{n-1}-n}$. This treats sequences which are rotations of each other as identical; if you count these as distinct, you recover the $2^{2^{n-1}}$ pattern you noticed.

Comment: Seems like a popular question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4501034/is-there-an-efficient-way-to-determine-whether-a-given-contiguous-sequence-can-a

Comment: Another approach to Q 4: If you are interested in *any* deBruijn sequence of length $2^n,$ you can just generate a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_length_sequence   corresponding to some primitive polynomial of degree $n$ over $GF(2)$ and insert a zero before or after the unique run of $n-1$ zeroes in that sequence.